# Changing sigma in Rattle for rbfdot Kernel

Tags: r, svm, radial, rattle

How can I change the sigma value in Rattle for the rbfdot kernel in SVM model?
I can change the cost function using eg: 'C-svc', 10

I use the options box to change these, if I type: 'C-svc','automatic', 10
I assume this means sigma is automatic however I cannot find a variation to set it to a value. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

From the R console, type

```
> ?ksvm
```

You will then see the manual page for the ksvm() function. The various parameters are listed there. Then in rattle you can provide those Options like:

```
type="C-svc", kpar=list(sigma=0.05)
```